# Why won't video from ffmpeg show in QuickTime, iMovie or quick preview?

Tags: video, imovie, quicktime, encoding

I've been using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) for the occasional video conversion for quite some time, and recently discovered that H.264 (libx264) videos generated by ffmpeg aren't working in iMovie or QuickTime (nor will they play or show a preview in Finder with the quick view feature).

If I generate videos using OS X applications which internally use ffmpeg (e.g. [MP4tools](http://www.emmgunn.com/mp4tools/mp4toolshome.html) or [Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/)) the videos work fine, but not when I try to use ffmpeg directly, e.g. to convert a video:

```
# ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4
```

or to combine some images into a video:

```
# ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type sequence image-%04d.png output.mp4
```

iMovie just imports the video as black/blank, quick preview just shows the file info, (but no video preview), and Quicktime tells me it cannot play it:

[image: document could not be opened]

What's going on?!

Answer (score 52):

In short, you (often) need to include the argument `-pix_fmt yuv420p` when using ffmpeg to generate H.264 content for Apple software/devices, and a bunch of other decoders that don't handle yuv444p.

```
# ffmpeg -i input.avi -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

This is not mentioned in the output when using the defaults, but can be found in their [Encode/H.264 guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

It [turns out](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2214#no1) that ffmpeg have chosen a default pixel format of yuv444p for libx264 encoding (under some circumstances), which is not compatible with Apple's software/hardware H.264 decoders (and [perhaps not very widely compatible in general?](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=808)). Unfortunately this seems unlikely to change, and there's no warning about it, so just something you have to know if using ffmpeg to make H.264 files.

As far as I can tell, if converting a video that's already using yuv420p it'll maintain that, but if converting from something a bit more exotic (e.g. images or a GIF or whatever) the pixel format must be specified for general Apple compatibility.

Comment: Does not help in current version of iMovie (Yosemite). Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ffprobe -select_streams v -show_streams output.mp4`?

Comment: +1, even yuv420p videos are not playing in High Sierra as well.

Comment: Not just Apple, but also Windows media player sometimes can't play the output if you don't specify that option. And if you try playing it with other players, it would be a comeple gray screen with artifacts showing on video.

Comment: Just wanted to add this worked for me in 2020, with Catalina 10.15.5 and ffmpeg 4.3. Thanks!

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm finding on Ventura 13.5, that `-pix_fmt yuv420p` works for HEVC and h264, but `-vf format=yuv420p` does **not**. From the link:

`Encoding for dumb players: You may need to use -vf format=yuv420p (or the alias -pix_fmt yuv420p) for your output to work in QuickTime and most other players.`

I made a movie QuickTime will open:
`ffmpeg  -r 60 -f image2 -pattern_type glob -I 'frame.*.png' -r 60 -c:v libx265 -crf 28  -tag:v hvc1 -pix_fmt yuv420p  test5hevc.mov`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `yuv420p`, some discoveries on codecs in 2021 (Catalina 10.15.7 and Monterey 12.0.1, imovie 10.3 and 10.2.5, ffmpeg 4.4).

Not all `*264` *codecs* are the same. The `-c:v libx264` codec cannot be consistently imported. Instead, use `-c:v h264_videotoolbox`.

This is true across "Apple silicon" (aka ARM) and Intel CPUs.

Neither libx265 nor hevc_videotoolbox can be imported consistently, if at all.

(edit, days later, I had a video that wouldn't import with `-c:v hd264_videotoolbox`. It **did** work with `-c:v copy -c:a copy`, so one more thing to try)

Comment: Well the last line, c:v copy means it didn't create a new video, just copied everything as it was from some other source.